ESLint only runs locally (not github actions). Ignore patternt and src pattern conflict
It seems to be a weird bug where I'm fairly certain that I don't have any eslint ignore directory rules, and I in fact have eslint problems from the directory in question both from CLI and vscode on local machine. I suppose that a round about solution would be for github actions to not consider the push to broken if some sub directory of the directory I'm actually linting to supposedly be ignored.
GitHub Actions error message:
> npx eslint src/** *.{js,jsx,ts,tsx} --fix


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.57.0

You are linting "src/api", but all of the files matching the glob pattern "src/api" are ignored.

If you don't want to lint these files, remove the pattern "src/api" from the list of arguments passed to ESLint.

Workflow:
name: GitHub Actions Demo
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - deploy
jobs:
  everything:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # container:
    #   image: cypress/included
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Cypress install
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          # Disable running of tests within install job
          runTests: false
          build: npm install
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          start: npm run dev
      - name: Run ESLint
        run: npm run lint
      - name: Update Schema
        run: npm run updateSchema
      - name: deploy
        uses: cloudflare/wrangler-action@v3
        with:
          apiToken: ${{ secrets.CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN }}


import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";
import eslintPluginUnicorn from "eslint-plugin-unicorn";
import eslintConfigPrettier from "eslint-config-prettier";

export default [
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  eslintPluginUnicorn.configs['flat/recommended'],

  // ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  // ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked,

  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: globals.browser,
      parserOptions: {
        project: true,
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
        tsconfigRootDir: import.meta.dirname,
      },
    },
    rules: {
      // "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error",
      "unicorn/filename-case": [
        "error",
        {
          case: "camelCase",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  // pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  // // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  // eslintPluginUnicorn.configs["flat/recommended"],
  // // //...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  // // ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked,
  // eslintConfigPrettier,
];


I see three changes that would likely fix the bug you’re encountering.
1/
Amend package.json:

There is a typo in the lint script: ** * instead of **/*
Explicitly provide the path to your eslint.config.mjs file, to prevent any non-deterministic behavior where a specific environment (including your editor) might have some global override you’re not aware of.

{
  "lint": "eslint eslint.config.mjs src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx} --fix",
}

2/
Double-check to make sure that your tsconfig.json also includes all the files in your lint scope. The tsconfig scope must be wider than your lint scope (EDIT 2024/06/23: Only true when linting files included in TypeScript transpilation).
For example:
{
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.js",
    "./src/**/*.jsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
  ]
}


the 2nd part caused nodejs to stop running in cypress, but eslint still works.

I was just researching Cyprus a bit more @janat08 , can you share the error message that you are getting? Also, could you share your entire .tsconfig? Happy to help with debugging.

Everything works without the 2nd part. Eslint still works without it.

@janat08, just to confirm, ESLint is now successfully running in your CI environment?

yes it does, 1st part solved it.

Ok that is great, thanks for confirming

@janat08 FYI, I was wrong about Part 2 (see Edit in answer if you're interested), so you are right that Part 1 alone should fix it (and makes sense that Part 2 caused NodeJs to stop running in Cypress). I apologize for my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out to me, you caused me to realize my error much later on.

This worked for me:
"lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
Basically don't miss the single quote on the pattern.
